# Memory issue in JMImageCache

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory-leaks

I have implemented 
[JMImageCache](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache) for downlaoding images.Its classes have arc enable.

I am downloading images from url and displaying 6 images at a time in a view and on click next button another 6 images are loading in the same view(replacing previous one).

My problem is that on every click of next and previous my memory is increases by 2 MB. Is there any way to avoid it.

I have tried to manually release the objects but still memory is increasing (lesser compare to arc enable).

Answer (score 0):

This is due caching, to make things faster.You need to clear the cache, when you receive memory waring. Thats its.

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```